# How to disable middle click paste Mavericks Terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse

I have looked all over the Net and can't find a way to disable middle-click paste in the Terminal application in Mavericks?
I want it scroll but not paste.

Anybody know how to fix this? I'd sure appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/index.html.en) (formerly known as KeyRemap4MacBook) with the following setting in private.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <appdef>
        <appname>Terminal</appname>
        <equal>com.apple.Terminal</equal>
    </appdef>
    <item>
        <name>Disable middle-click</name>
        <identifier>private.disablemiddleclick</identifier>
        <only>Terminal</only>
        <autogen>
            __PointingButtonToKey__ PointingButton::MIDDLE, KeyCode::VK_NONE
        </autogen>
    </item>
</root>
```

Comment: This disables middle click globally, not just in Terminal.app. Is there a solution that only affects Terminal.app?

Comment: @tubes See edit which restricts this to only when Terminal is the frontmost app. This is what I originally intended but the code to restrict it to Terminal wasn't included by the user who added the full private.xml wrapper.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without Karabiner? Karabiner caused some problems (disabled my hyperdock window movement hotkeys somehow). I also couldn't find the `private.xml` file. :/

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get Karabiner working, but you can use this to disable middle click (or anything else) globally: http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Download.html