# How to disable middle click?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, mouse, keybindings, macos

Middle click to paste is making scrolling impossible in Terminal on my thinkpad keyboard because of middle click pasting.

I'd prefer to just disable it on that app, but globally would be fine.

I found this question with 1 answer but I had too much trouble with Karabiner (it broke hyperdock) and it's specifically about how to disable middle click for terminal, not globally: [How to disable middle click paste Mavericks Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/141945/how-to-disable-middle-click-paste-mavericks-terminal)

Answer (score 1):

This works! http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Download.html

You can disable any key you want on any device.

Answer (score 1):

Another suitable app is [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html).